# Removing Warning Image

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How to remove The warning image of the alert box in Javascript. I want to delete the warning image from the javascript alert window. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the look-and-feel of the result of an `alert()` call is browser dependent.  Each browser implements it differently.

If you need to change the look of a browser dialog box, you'll have to implement your own.  There's a lot of options out there.  [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is a particularly popular one if you happen to be using JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to change it. Better use a custom alert box.

[**jQuery Impromptu**](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)

is a nice one with a lot of options